# PHP Browser Detection IE > 6

Tags: php, browser

Alright, so Im working on some code in my companies repo, and I stumbled across this bit of browser detection in the login checks. That pretty much searches for MSIE specifically, and wants to decline the login if the browser version is `<= 6` however. This is a rather flawed concept at the moment. Seeing as the method takes the user agent string and removes everything but the version number, however the version number in this case is a single digit which works great for version 1-9 detection. However with Internet explorer 10, the result is 1, thus breaking the logic and making it useless.

So right now I am stuck trying to keep this logic for the most part the same, but in essence compensating for versions that would need 2 digits, such as 10+

its been a long while since I've done any browser detection thats version specific. So Im hoping someone can either help me tweak this little bit, or point me towards some better / newer functionality I might be able to use in the same manor.

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
    $ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    if (strstr($ua,'MSIE') && substr($ua,strpos($ua,'MSIE')+5,1) <= 6 ) {
        return $this->renderMessage(
            self::TEXT_LOGIN_FAILED,
            'It seems that your browser is currently unsupported. We apologize for any inconveniences. Please switch to another browser and try again.'
            );
    }
}
```

Above is what I am currently working with, as you can see its a bit messy, the person who made it originally didn't think to far a head. And Im stuck not wanting to break it, as I want to keep it similar but not if that makes any sense.

Comment: Use `preg_match` to extract a 1 or 2 digit section of the string (`/[0-9]{1,2}/`), and see if that's less than 6.

Comment: And do you have to do this? I mean, relying on correct data from `HTTP_USER_AGENT` is not a good idea in general...

Comment: preg_match might not work so well as a full user agent string would have multiple numbers to match eg: `Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; Trident/6.0`. @Jasper no I don't need to rely on user_agent so long as theres some means of getting a version if there is one to be found.

Comment: But I do need some form of version detection specifically around IE at the moment, as the software being developed will not work in 6 or below on IE

Comment: @chris: what I meant with that comment wasn't that you should look for another way to single out a browser, as it's the one way to single out browsers. However, it would be much better not to be so blunt about this and instead just display a message based on the user agent but not block the site based on it. That way, if things break people are on their own but aren't arbitrarily barred from your site if another browser identifies itself as old IE. On top of that, you should make sure that no harm can be done by IE 6 users, as users with malicious intent can still use any browser they want.

Comment: Under almost every circumstance I would agree with you on that Jasper, I am not keen on locking someone out based on Browser/Version. However in this case the external software that works with the browser side stuff, in the event the browser doesn't support a handful of key components, will lead to an improperly configured client side app, which will result in some cases corruption of data. We have a version of the app that is specific to systems that meet an older systems criteria, that gets configured through another means. No one is left behind, they just get handled differently :-D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
$ua_array = explode(' ', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$msie_key = array_search('MSIE', $ua_array);
if($msie_key !== false) { // you found MSIE browser
    $msie_version_key = $msie_key + 1;
    $msie_version = intval($ua_array[$msie_version_key]);
    if ($msie_version <= 6) {
        // reject user
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, thats clever, I see what you did there nice use of explode.